# rails undefined method when iterating of array of methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a rails beginner and trying to put some code in the model. The code below is an illustration.

View:

```
Player_stats: <%= @player.player_pass_completion_ratio %>
```

Model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :lefthandstats
 has_many :righthandstats

def player_pass_completion_ratio
 Hands = [ lefthandstats, righthandstats] #These are objects & calling   @player.lefthandstats.find_with_passes directly generally works

 if self.category ==  "Hands"
  total_usual_passes = 500
  Hands.each do |cmethod|
    if self.cmethod.find_with_passes(:passes, :first, {:conditions => 'passes>200' })   then accuratestats += 1 end
  end
 end

accuracy = (accuratestats/total_usual_passes)*100
end
```

I get an undefined method "cmethod" when I try to call the code from the view. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the first line of the method, what this seems to be saying is that you want to place two local variables names `lefthandstats` and `righthandstats` in an array called Hands. But, since this is the first line in the method, these two variables havn't been defined so they are nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is calling `self.cmethod`, which will try to call the `cmethod` method on your object (which doesn't exist).

I believe what you're trying to do is something like the following:

```
hands = [:lefthandstats, :righthandstats]
hands.each do |cmethod|
  self.send(cmethod).... #rest of your code goes here
end
```

This will dynamically call the `lefthandstats` and `righthandstats` methods on your object.

Answer (score 2):

Comments in ruby use the `#` character, not `//`

Comment: while this is true, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of "self.cmethod" and just use "cmethod"

```
if cmethod.find_with_passes....
```

In the scope of the block "cmethod" is just a local variable. By putting self in front of it, ruby assumed you were calling a method on the containing class instance.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I took it off and now get `undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass`. Is it okay to pass methods in a block the way I have implemented?

Comment: the more I'm looking at it, the code as written can't work. You have two 'somethings' in an array called `Hands`. To have this work, the 'something' that your calling `find_with_passes` on must have that method defined.  You say that `lefthandstat` is an object. What type of object?

Comment: BTW, the `undedeinfed method nil:NilClass` is because the objects in the "Hands" array are nil.

Comment: `@player.lefthandstats.find_with_passes` generally works and now I want to generalize it as a method I can call on a group of specific child objects of `@player` (lefthandstats, righthandsstats, leftfoot, rightfoot...)

Comment: Ok, I think that @sevenseacat's answer might be what you're looking for. By creating an array containing symbols `:lefthandstats` instead of variables `lefthandstats` you can then pass that symbol into a `send` method.

Comment: You are right, @sevenseacat's suggestion seems to be working. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First correct your code by replacing `//` by `#` as in rails we use `#` to comment the code as mentioned by akofink.

Then consider this in context of your code:

```
@result = Player.all

@result.each do |player|

player.name

end
```

Here `@result` is returning a collection of players. So you can use a loop with `@result.each` such that for each result as player, you are getting a name of each player.

Correct your code with the knowledge of what is in the above.